Quarkus Rest Client Builder and Fault Tolerance
Wondering if does QuarkusRestClientBuilder supports to MP Faul Tolerance annotations?
Thanks
The class we pass to build() method has the @Retry annotation but seems in this way (programatically creating the client) it does no supports it.

I expect it to work. Do you have an example project where it doesn't?
